# Best way for check if a variable is a whole number

Tags: c#

I need to check if a variable is a whole number and i have a lot of easy solutions.

The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612839/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-whole-number-c) is

> if (floor(foobar) == foobar)

And the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer) is

> if(d % 1 == 0)

The another one is convert this number to string and split by dot(.) and check second number is "00" of not

> d.toString().split('.')[1/]=="00"

But i think it is not a best practice.

A lot of these type of way, i want a standerd solution which is acceptable by all.

Comment: There is actually some discussion in the comments on the answers you linked about this..

Comment: Absent any other criteria, which do you find more readable?

Comment: here's another one ``(int)d == d``

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a decimal/double is an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer)

Comment: You cannot choose if you don't know what you need. Write down your exact requirements and validate whether either fulfills all requirements. If both do, roll a die.

Comment: `(int)d == d` will return false if d is outside the integer-range

Comment: Considering that the first answer is about C++, perhaps you have bigger problems than choosing the best one...

Comment: @Dennis_E If that matters use a cast to ``long`` insead

Comment: @Dennis no, it'll throw.

Comment: @Binkan and now the input is an `ulong`.

Comment: Best means "Fast in execution" and "Less Load on Server"

Comment: @mayank that is micro-optimization and you should not care.

Comment: @mayank Each way is *fast*, why do you even bother it?

Comment: @CodeCaster No it won't throw.

Comment: @Binkan Salaryman. Then it will fail if d is outside the long-range.

Comment: Don't try to learn billions of "best" ways to write code. Write clear, understandable code and set performance goals. Then measure the performance. If the performance is unacceptable, isolate *where* the code is performing badly and look to optimize there.

Comment: if type of variable d is Double, then what about "(int)d == d"

Comment: @Dennis_E stop being pedantic, you got the idea how it should work

Comment: `Best means "Fast in execution" and "Less Load on Server"`. This is probably premature optimization. Do you think this code will be called so many times that the performance will suffer. If yes, have you measured it?

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman But it doesn't work. That's the whole point.

Comment: @Dennis you're right, I thought `checked` was default.

Answer (score 10):

I'd probably go with

```
(d % 1) < epsilon
```

from the comment thread in the linked question. It's slower than both your examples so you can probably only do it a few million times per second as opposed to a few million times per second. On the plus side it handles floating point drift and min and max values quite well

Comment: +1 for "a few million as opposed to a few million". Premature optimization is indeed the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can use built in function int.TryParse()

```cs
int x;
bool result= int.TryParse(integerNumber.ToString(), out x);
```

if result is true then integer otherwise not.

Comment: Not quite. Not all whole number `doubles` are valid integers. `int.TryParse((int.MaxValue + 1.0).ToString(), out _)` return `false`!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, `(int)d == d` is the best in regards to readability.

I don't know about execution times, though.

Comment: The `int.MaxValue` is quite small if compared to `double.MaxValue`